# How to register custormize serializer for flink kafka format type

Tags: apache-flink

I create table as below, and the data is from kafka.
I want to deserialize the json message to Pojo object.
But the message format is not avro or simple json.
So I need to know how to register custormized serializer and use it for the 'format.type' property.
By the way, my flink version is 1.10.0.

```
CREATE TABLE MyUserTable(
 uuid VARCHAR,
 orgId VARCHAR
) with (
'connector.type' = 'kafka', 
'connector.version' = '0.11',
'connector.topic' = 'topic_name',
'connector.properties.zookeeper.connect' = 'localhost:2181',
'connector.properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
 'connector.properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
 'format.type' = 'cutormizeSerializer'
)
```

The kafka message body sample, each columnName is the key for Pojo object, and rawData is value:

```
{
    "beforeData": [],
    "byteSize": 272,
    "columnNumber": 32,
    "data": [{
        "byteSize": 8,
        "columnName": "APPLY_PERSON_ID",
        "rawData": 10017,
        "type": "LONG"
    }, {
        "byteSize": 12,
        "columnName": "UPDATE_SALARY",
        "rawData": "11000.000000",
        "type": "DOUBLE"
    }, {
        "byteSize": 11,
        "columnName": "UP_AMOUNT",
        "rawData": "1000.000000",
        "type": "DOUBLE"
    }, {
        "byteSize": 3,
        "columnName": "CURRENCY",
        "rawData": "CNY",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "byteSize": 32,
        "columnName": "EXCHANGE_RATE",
        "rawData": "1.000000000000000000000000000000",
        "type": "DOUBLE"
    },  {
        "byteSize": 11,
        "columnName": "DEDUCTED_ACCOUNT",
        "rawData": "1000.000000",
        "type": "DOUBLE"
    }, {
        "byteSize": 1,
        "columnName": "ENTER_AT_PROCESS",
        "rawData": "Y",
        "type": "STRING"
    }],
    "dataCount": 0,
    "dataMetaData": {
        "connector": "mysql",
        "pos": 1000368076,
        "row": 0,
        "ts_ms": 1625565737000,
        "snapshot": "false",
        "db": "testdb",
        "table": "flow_person_t"
    },
    "key": "APPLY_PERSON_ID",
    "memorySize": 1120,
    "operation": "insert",
    "rowIndex": -1,
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
}
```

The Pojo object as below:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class HrSalaryPersonVO {
    private String uuid;
    private String orgId;
    private String unitId;
    private String effectiveDate;

    private int adjustPersonCount;

    private Double adjustAmount;

    private Double beforeSalaryAmount;
    private Double adjustRate;

    private String data0prateType;

    private String status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement you own `DeserializationFactory` like shown [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.10/flink-formats/flink-json/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/formats/json/JsonRowFormatFactory.java). The factory needs to be added to the `META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactory` file to be discovered in the DDL string.

Note that this example is for Flink 1.10 as requested. Users of newer Flink versions can take a look at the [full connector example](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-table/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/examples/java/connectors) that includes defining a custom format. The new stack extends from `org.apache.flink.table.factories.DecodingFormatFactory/EncodingFormatFactory`. And uses the `META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.table.factories.Factory` service file.